# Why is VS Code treating .cs files as plain text, but everything else normally?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, intellisense, visual-studio-code

I have a Unity Project open in Visual Studio Code, with 3 `.csproj` files, a `launch.json` and `settings.json` file. I'm using the [VS Code](https://github.com/dotBunny/VSCode/) plug-in for unity, and the [Unity Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tobiah.unity-tools) extension for VS Code.
If I open a `.js` script, VS Code treats it as such, and all the highlighting happens. But if I open a `.cs` script, it treats it as a Plain Text document, and I get no formatting or IntelliSense. If I try to select the language manually, I can select most any language I like, except for C#, which is missing from the list.
[image: screenshot of the .cs and the .js files side by side]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manually install C# support.  It looks like it was made optional in the [February update](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/vFebruary) of Code.

Type `F1` to get to the command window and type `ext install` to install extensions.  Get the C# extension and restart Code.

See the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp) for more information on C# support.